# List column hyperlinks are not clickable

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, hyperlink

I have a list inside it I have a hyperlink column with items like www.google.com and www.youtube.com. I can retreive the list items and show on my site the problem is I get only the url and its not clickable. Anyone have clue how to fix it? I tried with ahref tags like this. I want every hyperlink item to be clickable.

```
while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var listItem = enumerator.get_current();

            itemString += listItem.get_item('Title') + "<br/>" + "<a href" + listItem.get_item('Link').get_url() + "</a>";

            $('#divAllaListItems').html(itemString);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an incorrect anchor tag. You'd want it to be something like this:

```
itemString += "<a href='" + listItem.get_item('Link').get_url() + "'>"+listItem.get_item('Title') +"</a>";
```

Comment: Okey thank you, I tested it now I dont get any errors but I get this message: "Property or the field has not been initialized. There has been no request or has not been performed. It may need to be requested specifically." In my list I added some links under hyperlink column.